# Mechanism of Wiliamson Synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

I was studying about Williamson's Synthesis, and my textbook had the following statement:

> Williamson's Synthesis is a nucleophilic substitution reaction and proceeds via $\ce{S_N2}$ mechanism.

Then there was this reaction shown as an example:

> [image]

It says that the reaction proceeds through a slow $\ce{S_N1}$ mechanism.

Now I searched on the internet and saw that Williamson's synthesis proceeds through $\ce{S_N1}$ mechanism. In that case, what about the shown example? Is what my textbook says correct? Or is there any finer detail?

Comment: It depends on the alkyl halide substrate

Comment: That means, reactions involving primary alky halides proceed through SN2, while those of tertiary alkyl halide substrates proceed through SN1 mechanism?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: @Nilabja  and secondary halides proceed by both hence the example given

Comment: If you got your answer, feel free to self answer it. Self answering is appreciated and it also help future readers.

Comment: @Waylander I have read in my textbook (Organic Chemistry for JEE Advanced, Cengage Publications) and in the standard class 12 textbook of India (NCERT) that alkoxide being a strong nucleophile proceeds *only* through SN2 mechanism. Is there a disparity?

Comment: @Waylander in the same context the textbook also mentioned that Williamson synthesis was not a good method for secondary alkyl halides (as in secondary substrate elimination competes with SN2) and also not for tertiary alkyl halides (which don't give SN2 and hence elimination being the only product). Is what I have learnt wrong?

Comment: @TRC Saying that Williamson proceeds only by SN2 is going too far. It certainly goes better when SN2 is the dominant mechanism. There are plenty of examples of ether formation between tertiary species and primary alcohols. Search "tritylation of ethanol" for examples, though whether these reactions classify as Williamson is moot.

Comment: @Waylander In the general case, does it prefer SN2 to an extent where yields with secondary and tertiary halides are low enough to favour elimination as the major product? The textbook mainly emphasized on questions asking for the best method of ether synthesis, given the ether - and for secondary or tertiary halides the best method mentioned would be alkoxymercuration-demercuration.

Comment: You always get some elimination with Williamson conditions but yes, with secondary and tertiary it can become significant.  Williamson works best for systems like methyl or benzyl halides where there are no alpha hydrogens. No-one in the real world uses mercuration - the hazards are too great.  The trichloroacetimidate chemistry is a good alternative.